# Joins for queries

Tags: mysql, join

I am preparing for my exams this week and I saw a past paper question like this:

***Lecturer***

```
lec_id
lec_name
phone
dept
```

***requests***

```
lec_id
book_id 
qty 
date
```

***book***

```
book_id
title
author
cost
supplier
```

I need to write a MySQL command that will find the name and phone number of each lecturer requesting the book with id# 123.

I tried creating the query as shown below:

```
SELECT lec_name, phone FROm lecturer 
  LEFT JOIN requests ON requests.lec_id = lecturer.lec_id 
  LEFT JOIN requests ON requests.book_id = book.book_id
WHERE book.book_id = 123
```

However I keep getting the error Not unique table/alias: 'requests'

Answer (score 0):

Best to start from the **book** so the WHERE clause is cleaner, and perhaps more intuitively adapted to searching for another specific book and/or all books:

```
select book.book_id, book.title, lecturer.lec_name, lecturer.phone 
from book
left join requests on book.book_id = requests.book_id
left join Lecturer on requests.lec_id = Lecturer.lec_id 
where book.book_id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lec_name, phone FROm lecturer 
  LEFT JOIN requests ON requests.lec_id = lecturer.lec_id 
  AND requests.book_id = book.book_id
WHERE book.book_id = 123
```